# how to play mp3 in asset url using AVPlayer

Tags: ios7, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

i have url in ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=8788117795090152241
how to play mp3 in this url

```
   AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url_selectedSong];
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[player play];
```

but not play song

Comment: see the link same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943336/mpmediaitem-not-playing-in-avaudioplayer-using-mpmediaitempropertyasseturl?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```c
NSError * error;
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

if(player) {
    [player play];
}
```